# Dynamically create SFTP reader with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

My multi-tenant application needs to periodically check a set of SFTP folders for an ingestion file. The SFTP folders and parameters are defined in my application.properties file, and the number is dynamic.

```
ingestion.carriers=carrier1,carrier2

ingestion.carrier1=sftp
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.host=localhost
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.username=sftp
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.password=sftp
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.remotedir=carrier1
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.localdir=sftp/carrier1
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.archivedir=sftp/carrier1/archive
ingestion.carrier1.sftp.errordir=sftp/carrier1/error
ingestion.carrier1.ping=7000

ingestion.carrier2=sftp
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.host=localhost
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.username=sftp
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.password=sftp
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.remotedir=carrier2
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.localdir=sftp/carrier2
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.archivedir=sftp/carrier2/archive
ingestion.carrier2.sftp.errordir=sftp/carrier2/error
ingestion.carrier2.pingFrequency=13000
```

I need to dinamically create all the necessary beans to enable spring integration flow. To do so, I've tried to set up a BeanFactoryPostProcessor, as I cannot declare the beans in a "static" way. This processor is thought to be configured, in future, with different methods to retrieve the file: because of this, the actual creation of beans is delegated to another class.

This is the post processor...

```
package mypkg.batch.config.integration;

import mypkg.batch.config.integration.factory.SFTPBeansFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;

@Component
public class IngestionBeanConfigurator implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IngestionBeanConfigurator.class);

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory fact) throws BeansException {
        Environment env = fact.getBean(Environment.class);
        String carriersList = env.getProperty("ingestion.carriers");
        if (carriersList == null) {
            LOG.info("No ingestion has been defined");

            return;
        }
        List<String> carriers = List.of(carriersList.split(","));

        for (String carrier : carriers) {
            String carrierMethod = env.getProperty("ingestion.%s".formatted(carrier));
            if (carrierMethod != null) {
                if ("sftp".equals(carrierMethod)) {
                    new SFTPBeansFactory(carrier, env).loadBeans(fact);
                } else {
                    LOG.warn("Invalid carrier method {} for carrier {}", carrierMethod, carrier);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

... and this is the class creating SFTP beans

```
package com.eyemed.foodogs.batch.config.integration.factory;

import com.eyemed.foodogs.model.exception.MembersMessageHandler;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.MessageChannelSpec;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.context.IntegrationFlowContext;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.filters.SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory;

import java.io.File;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SFTPBeansFactory implements BeanFactory {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SFTPBeansFactory.class);

    private final String carrierId;

    private final String sftpHost;
    private final String sftpUsername;
    private final String sftpPassword;
    private final String sftpRemoteDir;
    private final String sftpLocalDir;
    private final String sftpArchiveDir;
    private final String sftpErrorDir;

    private final BigInteger pingFrequency;

    public SFTPBeansFactory(final String carrierId, final Environment props) {
        String prefix = "ingestion.%s".formatted(carrierId);

        this.carrierId = carrierId;

        this.sftpHost = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.host".formatted(prefix));
        this.sftpUsername = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.username".formatted(prefix));
        this.sftpPassword = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.password".formatted(prefix));
        this.sftpRemoteDir = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.remotedir".formatted(prefix));
        this.sftpLocalDir = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.localdir".formatted(prefix));
        this.sftpArchiveDir = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.archivedir".formatted(prefix));
        this.sftpErrorDir = props.getProperty("%s.sftp.errordir".formatted(prefix));

        String pingFrequencyString = props.getProperty("%s.ping".formatted(prefix));
        if (pingFrequencyString != null) {
            this.pingFrequency = new BigInteger(pingFrequencyString);
        } else {
            this.pingFrequency = BigInteger.valueOf(3600000);
        }
    }

    public void loadBeans(ConfigurableBeanFactory fact) {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf = _buildSessionFactory();

        SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync = _buildInboundFileSynchronizer(sf);
        fact.registerSingleton("sftp-sync-%s".formatted(carrierId), sync);

        SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource src = _buildMessageSource(sync);
        MembersMessageHandler handler = new MembersMessageHandler(carrierId, fact.getBean(JobLauncher.class), fact.getBean("readMembersJob", Job.class));

        String beanName = "sftp-flow-%s".formatted(carrierId);
        String channelName = "sftp-ingestion-channel-%s".formatted(carrierId);

        LOG.info("Creating bean %s based on channel %s".formatted(beanName, channelName));

        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(src, c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(pingFrequency.longValue(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 0)))
                .channel(channelName)
                .handle(handler)
                .get();

        IntegrationFlowContext ctx = fact.getBean(IntegrationFlowContext.class);
        ctx.registration(flow).id(beanName).autoStartup(true).register();

        flow.start();
    }

    private SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource _buildMessageSource(SftpInboundFileSynchronizer sync) {
        var src = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(sync);
        src.setLocalDirectory(new File(sftpLocalDir));
        src.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        src.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>());
        return src;
    }

    private SftpInboundFileSynchronizer _buildInboundFileSynchronizer(DefaultSftpSessionFactory sf) {
        var sync = new SftpInboundFileSynchronizer(sf);
        sync.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        sync.setRemoteDirectory(sftpRemoteDir);
        sync.setFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));

        sync.setLocalFilenameGeneratorExpressionString(
                "#this.substring(0, #this.length - 4) + '_%s_' + new com.eyemed.foodogs.application.util.TimestampProvider().currentTimestamp() + '.txt'".formatted(carrierId));
        return sync;
    }

    private DefaultSftpSessionFactory _buildSessionFactory() {
        var sf = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost(sftpHost);
        sf.setUser(sftpUsername);
        sf.setPassword(sftpPassword);
        sf.setPort(22);
        sf.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return sf;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work: SFTP files are not read and remain sadly in the source folder. The local SFTP works, as the previous version with the "static" beans used to work correctly.

Also, I do not see errors in the log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.5)

2022-10-18 11:42:15.396  INFO 8226 --- [           main] com.eyemed.foodogs.application.App       : Starting App using Java 17 on A-M-L-MUTI.local with PID 8226 (/Users/lorenzomuti/Repositories/FooDogs/backend/foodogsbootapplication/target/classes started by lorenzomuti in /Users/lorenzomuti/Repositories/FooDogs/backend/foodogsbootapplication)
2022-10-18 11:42:15.399  INFO 8226 --- [           main] com.eyemed.foodogs.application.App       : The following profiles are active: dev
2022-10-18 11:42:17.988  INFO 8226 --- [           main] c.e.f.b.c.i.factory.SFTPBeansFactory     : Creating bean sftp-flow-carrier1 based on channel sftp-ingestion-channel-carrier1
2022-10-18 11:42:18.028  INFO 8226 --- [           main] c.e.f.b.c.i.factory.SFTPBeansFactory     : Creating bean sftp-flow-carrier2 based on channel sftp-ingestion-channel-carrier2
2022-10-18 11:42:18.038  INFO 8226 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created.
2022-10-18 11:42:18.049  INFO 8226 --- [           main] faultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor : No bean named 'integrationHeaderChannelRegistry' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default DefaultHeaderChannelRegistry will be created.
2022-10-18 11:42:18.311  INFO 8226 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.IntegrationManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-18 11:42:18.322  INFO 8226 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationChannelResolver' of type [org.springframework.integration.support.channel.BeanFactoryChannelResolver] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-18 11:42:18.324  INFO 8226 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'integrationDisposableAutoCreatedBeans' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.annotation.Disposables] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-10-18 11:42:18.659  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-18 11:42:18.675  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-18 11:42:18.676  INFO 8226 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.53]
2022-10-18 11:42:18.816  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-18 11:42:18.816  INFO 8226 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3337 ms
2022-10-18 11:42:18.892 DEBUG 8226 --- [           main] o.s.w.f.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter      : Filter 'logFilter' configured for use
2022-10-18 11:42:19.474  INFO 8226 --- [           main] c.e.f.application.config.UnionPayConfig  : Activating UnionPay Service logger
2022-10-18 11:42:20.478  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
2022-10-18 11:42:20.501  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2022-10-18 11:42:20.730  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7a0f06ad, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3e9fb485, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@580ffea, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7fe87c0e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@c82d925, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@38dbeb39, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@48106381, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@1fa9692b, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2ffb0d10, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@f76872f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6df2a206]
2022-10-18 11:42:20.849  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {logging-channel-adapter:_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger} as a subscriber to the 'errorChannel' channel
2022-10-18 11:42:20.849  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : Channel 'application.errorChannel' has 1 subscriber(s).
2022-10-18 11:42:20.849  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean '_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger'
2022-10-18 11:42:20.867  INFO 8226 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-10-18 11:42:20.887  INFO 8226 --- [           main] com.eyemed.foodogs.application.App       : Started App in 6.399 seconds (JVM running for 7.221)
```

Is my approach correct? Should I do something more? Please help me, as I do not know where to bump my head :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider to move you logic into some `@PostConstruct` method instead.

I think getting access to bean factory and starting beans from the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is too early.

Also consider to use a `SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec` instead of manual creation. And don't register those beans manually - rely on the `IntegrationFlowContext`.

I wanted to suggest you to look into this also: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice.

But looks like you use that `carrierId` in the message handler. Although it may come as a message header. Not sure also if you really need that `.channel(channelName)` in between.

Comment: it worked! I "migrated" the code to rely on the application context and now it works perfectly :)
Later I'll post the final solution, but thanks!